# not able to get dynamic document.getElementById values

Tags: javascript

I'm having problems getting values from dynamicly added lines in a form.

I have a "add new line" button, and i would like to get values from the new line by using a onChange.

i can't figure out how to get this to work

This code adds my line :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 1;
    $(".add-row").click(function(){
        var markup = "<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='record'></input></td><td><select name='pris["+ counter +"][type]'><option value='ordi'>Ordinaer</option><option value='barn'>Barn</option></select>Belop<input type='text' name='pris["+ counter +"][pris]' value='0' id='pris_"+ counter +"'></input>Gebyr kr.<input class='bless' type='text' id='Gebyr_"+ counter +"' readonly disabled size='5'></input></td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='pris["+ counter +"][1]' checked>Internett</input><input type='checkbox' name='pris["+ counter +"][2]' checked>Callsenter</input><input type='checkbox' name='pris["+ counter +"][3]'>Distribusjon</input><input type='checkbox' name='pris["+ counter +"][4]'>Lokal Billettluke</input></td></tr>";
        counter++;
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
    });
```

i would like to have a function like this to work on all lines I add :

```
function Gebyr1(parameter) {
    var c = 1;
    var G10 = document.getElementById("pris_" + c).value;
    if (G10 <= 99){var G10_2 = '15';}
    else if (G10 >= 100 && G10 <= 249){var G10_2 = '20';}
    else if (G10 >= 250 && G10 <= 449){var G10_2 = '25';}
    else if (G10 >= 450 && G10 <= 699){var G10_2 = '30';}
    else if (G10 >= 700 && G10 <= 949){var G10_2 = '35';}
    else if (G10 >= 950 && G10 <= 1199){var G10_2 = '40';}
    else if (G10 >= 1200 && G10 <= 1449){var G10_2 = '45';}
    else if (G10 >= 1450 && G10 <= 1699){var G10_2 = '50';}
    else if (G10 >= 1700 && G10 <= 1949){var G10_2 = '55';}
    else if (G10 >= 1950 && G10 <= 2199){var G10_2 = '60';}
    else if (G10 >= 2200 && G10 <= 2449){var G10_2 = '65';}
    else if (G10 >= 2450 && G10 <= 2699){var G10_2 = '70';}
    else if (G10 >= 2700 && G10 <= 2949){var G10_2 = '75';}
    else if (G10 >= 2950 && G10 <= 3199){var G10_2 = '80';}
    document.getElementById("Gebyr_" + c).value = G10_2;
```

Comment: What you get when you do `console.log(document.getElementById("pris_1"))`?

Comment: If I may, as you can see, input tags close itself, `<input />` and not `<input></input>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/text, it won't respond to your question though but it'll be better for you after :)

Comment: Try this fiddle and tell me if it works : https://jsfiddle.net/1cqn73vy/, I only added the JS part, I don't have the HTML part

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery on() instead of click()

http://api.jquery.com/on/

$( "Selector for the container having dynamic dom" ).on( "click", "selector for your new row button inside this container", function() {
  console.log();
});

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as document.ready() is triggered once the page is loaded. For dynamic dom elements, you need to use JQuery on() API as mentioned by @sushil-mahajan or else you can use vanilla JS as below:

```
var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.addEventListener('click', eventHandler, false);
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

Then you can use `eventHandler()` to handle all clicks.

Also, you can use the below code:

```
document.querySelector('.className').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // add your event handler code here.
});
```